# azure virtual machine availability set

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-availability-set

I'm using the java api for Azure to automate the creation of vnets, subnets, and vm instances. What I want to be able to do is run code that creates a vnet, establishes an initial subnet inside that vnet, and then creates a VM with an Nic in that subnet. I was able to do this once with no issue, but when I tried it again I got this error:

Subnet  referenced by resource  is not in the same Virtual Network  as the subnets of other VMs in the availability set.

I haven't even created any availability sets. Why is it giving me this issue?

Thanks,

Adam

Here's the full text of the error response:

```
17:02:01,249 ERROR WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component AzureDriver for method public abstract java.util.concurrent.Future net.maxgigapop.mrs.driver.IHandleDriverSystemCall.commitDelta(net.maxgigapop.mrs.bean.DriverSystemDelta): javax.ejb.EJBException: com.microsoft.azure.CloudException: Subnet subnet-d39c3ca7-39c9-494a-9a82-a5812e9346f8 referenced by resource /subscriptions/08d719ed-dc6a-40a9-8e12-4e3a28ad01a6/resourceGroups/StackV/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic0/ipConfigurations/primary is not in the same Virtual Network /subscriptions/08d719ed-dc6a-40a9-8e12-4e3a28ad01a6/resourceGroups/StackV/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vpc-d530ea45-2a89-4360-8a71-8dcd62b9019a as the subnets of other VMs in the availability set.: Subnet subnet-d39c3ca7-39c9-494a-9a82-a5812e9346f8 referenced by resource /subscriptions/08d719ed-dc6a-40a9-8e12-4e3a28ad01a6/resourceGroups/StackV/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic0/ipConfigurations/primary is not in the same Virtual Network /subscriptions/08d719ed-dc6a-40a9-8e12-4e3a28ad01a6/resourceGroups/StackV/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vpc-d530ea45-2a89-4360-8a71-8dcd62b9019a as the subnets of other VMs in the availability set.
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.processInvocation(LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$2.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:104)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:74)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.CloudException: Subnet subnet-d39c3ca7-39c9-494a-9a82-a5812e9346f8 referenced by resource /subscriptions/08d719ed-dc6a-40a9-8e12-4e3a28ad01a6/resourceGroups/StackV/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic0/ipConfigurations/primary is not in the same Virtual Network /subscriptions/08d719ed-dc6a-40a9-8e12-4e3a28ad01a6/resourceGroups/StackV/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vpc-d530ea45-2a89-4360-8a71-8dcd62b9019a as the subnets of other VMs in the availability set.: Subnet subnet-d39c3ca7-39c9-494a-9a82-a5812e9346f8 referenced by resource /subscriptions/08d719ed-dc6a-40a9-8e12-4e3a28ad01a6/resourceGroups/StackV/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic0/ipConfigurations/primary is not in the same Virtual Network /subscriptions/08d719ed-dc6a-40a9-8e12-4e3a28ad01a6/resourceGroups/StackV/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vpc-d530ea45-2a89-4360-8a71-8dcd62b9019a as the subnets of other VMs in the availability set.
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.createExceptionFromResponse(AzureClient.java:724)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.access$100(AzureClient.java:33)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$3.call(AzureClient.java:160)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$3.call(AzureClient.java:157)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeSingle.call(OnSubscribeSingle.java:81)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeSingle.call(OnSubscribeSingle.java:27)
at rx.internal.operators.SingleToObservable.call(SingleToObservable.java:39)
at rx.internal.operators.SingleToObservable.call(SingleToObservable.java:27)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.DeferredScalarSubscriber.subscribeTo(DeferredScalarSubscriber.java:153)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.call(OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.java:32)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.call(OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.java:22)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: retrofit2.Response.class
at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73)
... 46 more
```

Comment: When you try to create Azure availability set and VM, azure will create the VNet first. According to the error you post, it should be the cause.So, check your code and see if the subnet is you referred is  same as the one in the Virtual Network which you're creating.